# What actually all these parameter means?

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, jit

Recently, I participated in an online coding test where I saw this command.

```
javac -J-Xms8m -J-Xmx8m -Xlint:none -XDsuppressNotes $file
```

Only I know is `-Xlint:none` is for turning JIT off, but want to know what other parameters do.

Comment: *"Only I know is `-Xlint:none` is for turning JIT off"* nope, that's for turning warnings off. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9

Comment: Sure, thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1):

**-Joptions**:
Using this you are passing option to the java launcher called by javac.

- -J-Xms48m sets the startup memory to 48 megabytes.

**-Xlint**
This option is for managing warnings. If no option is given it enables all recommended warnings.

- -Xlint:all Enable all recommended warnings.
- -Xlint:none Disable all warnings.
- -Xlint:name Enable warning name.
- -Xlint:-name Disable warning name.

**-XDsuppressNotes**
Disables notes. A compiler generates errors, warnings and notes. I could not get a note example from `javac`. I got one example from `gcc`

**note:** each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.